# What happens on the primary when log cannot be restored on the secondary on Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, disaster-recovery, log-shipping

I would like to setup a log shipping but I have a concern as to what would happen if the restore operation on the secondary would fail for some reason. I want the primary database keep working no matter what happens on the secondary database - even if the log restore can't be completed or secondary db goes offline. Does log shipping offer such an option?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concern you raise is not one you should need to worry about for Log Shipping.  Log Shipping is a group of jobs that act independently from each other, based on some schedule.  The job on the Primary backs up the transaction log to a location the Secondary can then access.  This is its primary function in life and it will continue to do it regardless of what's happening with the rest of your Log Shipping configuration (ex. restores failing on Secondary).  For that reason, you don't need to worry about your Primary being brought down due to the Secondary failing to apply its logs properly or having its databases go offline.  The Primary's transaction log backups will continue to run normally in these situations.